# Converting List to Data Frame

Tags: r, xml, list, loops, dataframe

I have a series of complex lists that I am trying to convert to data frame format in R. Each list will be converted to a data frame individually. Some of the lists have some values that are blank, making it hard to convert the list to a data frame.

I have tried lapply/ sapply to find the maximum length of the list and neither work. Additionally, using do.call and unlist does not give me the data in the format I want (it loses column titles and formats the table into three columns, rather than many columns). I found that the following code works on the first 5 lists:

```
max_list<-max(rapply(List, length))
df<-as.data.frame(rapply(List, function(x) 'length<-'(x, max_list), how="list"))
```

However, when I try to apply this in a loop for all of the lists, I get the following error.

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 0
```

My ultimate goal is for the parts of the list that have missing values to be converted to "NA."

Is there anything I can add to this code to avoid the error? Or is there something else that I can do to convert those lists that have differing numbers of rows?

**EDIT:**

I can't post my exact code for the inputs online but the list is nested and is very complex.

Example input:

```
iter1 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "a",item3="b")
iter2 <- list(item1 = 2, item2 = "c")
List <- list(iter1 = iter1, iter2 = iter2)
```

Ideally, I'd like for this output as a data frame:

```
V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
1      a      b      2      c
```

As mentioned, I was able to get this result with the code above. But, I'm not sure why the code is failing when applied to more complex lists.

Comment: Hi. Could you provide an example of your input and the desired output?

Comment: Please see [How to create a great reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DouglasMesquita please see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unlist` and the argument `recursive = T`.

```
df <- data.frame(as.list(unlist(x = List, recursive = T, use.names = F)))
names(df) <- paste0("V", 1:ncol(df))
df

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  a  b  2  c
```

To make it easier to read:

```
library(dplyr)

unlist(x = List, recursive = T, use.names = F) %>%
  as.list() %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(nm = paste0("V", 1:ncol(.)))

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  a  b  2  c
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.